# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener when using MyFaces with WASCE/Geronimo

Tags: java, jsf, myfaces, geronimo, websphere-ce

I am trying to create a simple JSF web application using MyFaces v 2.1 with WebSphere Application Server Community Edition v3.0.0.1 and Eclipse Juno but when I try to run the application the following error is returned:

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
org.apache.geronimo.common.DeploymentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
    at org.apache.geronimo.web25.deployment.AbstractWebModuleBuilder.createWebAppClassFinder(AbstractWebModuleBuilder.java:665)
    at org.apache.geronimo.web25.deployment.AbstractWebModuleBuilder.configureBasicWebModuleAttributes(AbstractWebModuleBuilder.java:698)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.deployment.TomcatModuleBuilder.addGBeans(TomcatModuleBuilder.java:469)
    at org.apache.geronimo.j2ee.deployment.SwitchingModuleBuilder.addGBeans(SwitchingModuleBuilder.java:174)
    at org.apache.geronimo.j2ee.deployment.EARConfigBuilder.buildConfiguration(EARConfigBuilder.java:764)
    at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:255)
    at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ReflectionMethodInvoker.java:34)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanOperation.invoke(GBeanOperation.java:131)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.invoke(GBeanInstance.java:883)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.invoke(BasicKernel.java:245)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.KernelGBean.invoke(KernelGBean.java:344)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ReflectionMethodInvoker.java:34)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanOperation.invoke(GBeanOperation.java:131)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.invoke(GBeanInstance.java:883)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.invoke(BasicKernel.java:245)
    at org.apache.geronimo.system.jmx.MBeanGBeanBridge.invoke(MBeanGBeanBridge.java:172)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1438)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(RMIConnectionImpl.java:83)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1276)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1378)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:799)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor73.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:171)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:167)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:547)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:802)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:661)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.apache.geronimo.hook.equinox.GeronimoClassLoader.loadClass(GeronimoClassLoader.java:85)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
    at org.apache.geronimo.web25.deployment.AbstractWebModuleBuilder.addClass(AbstractWebModuleBuilder.java:670)
    at org.apache.geronimo.web25.deployment.AbstractWebModuleBuilder.createWebAppClassFinder(AbstractWebModuleBuilder.java:661)
    ... 45 more
```

Presumably the error is occurring because the MyFaces jar files are not in the class path however I cannot figure out where I’m going wrong as the build path in Eclipse contains the required jars. I’ve also tried copying the jar files into the `WEB-INF/lib` directory but to no avail.

The screenshot below shows the project structure along with the libraries.

[image: Eclipse Project Structure]

Is there something specific I need to do either in Eclipse or WASCE to include the jar files or does the problem lie elsewhere?

Comment: Why the down vote? I've tried to explain the problem I've got as best I can and include all the information available.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
```

The missing class is part of [Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net), which is actually the competitor of [MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org).

You shouldn't need that class at all when using MyFaces. This exception can have the following possible causes:

- There's a manually definied `<listener>` entry in webapp's `web.xml` or the `web-fragment.xml` of any of the deployed JARs in `/WEB-INF/lib` which references this Mojarra-specific listener class.
- There's somewhere a loose Mojarra `.tld` file in the classpath (very unlikely, who would ever extract a JAR file and put its loose contents in the classpath?). TLD files get autoinitialized and can contain a `<listener>` entry which can trigger autoregistration of a `ServletContextListener` implementation (such as the Mojarra `ConfigureListener`).

Those conflicts can be fixed by just removing it.

Comment: Thanks - I've removed `<listener> <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class> </listener>` from the web.xml file and its now working :)

Answer (score 4):

I deployed an web application with Myfaces in a Jetty server and it was necessary to use a listener and an additional init parameter to use facelets:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.FACES_INITIALIZER </param-name>
    <param-value>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.FaceletsInitilializer</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was using mojarra implementation for compilation and was relying on apache tomcat for runtime. But tomcat uses myfaces implementation. So had to include mojarra impl jar in the WEB-INF/lib to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

I was with the same problem. When I tried to run a .html file with Eclipse using Tomcat7 as the local server I received the 404 error on the Browser. And in Eclipse's console was showing the error "ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".

The problem was the Mojarra library (.jar) I was using in my Dynamic Web project. I was using the javax.faces-2.3.0-m04.jar.

-> Solution:

Download an older version on Mojarra's repositories https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/javax.faces/ . In my case, I downloaded the 2.2.7 version (javax.faces-2.2.7.jar).

Then I created a new Dynamic Web project in Eclipse using JSF v2.0 and assigned with the javax.faces-2.2.7.jar file in the library section.