# Migration from richfaces 3.1.6 to 3.3.3 has java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, richfaces

Good evening guys.
Thank you so much in advance for giving up your time to just read my problem, and i'll appreciate it if someone could help me.

I'm responsible now for migrating a big project from richefaces 3.1.6 to 3.3.3, but i'm stuck having this issue at the startup of tomcat: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener

The same issue has been reported in this link: [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777844/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-faces-config-configurelistener-when-us). But it's may be way different than the one i'm facing. 
I tried many configuration(like changing jsf implementation to mojarra) but with no conclusive result.
Now I'm trying to go with it step by step, and seek your help when I'm stuck.

Here are the old list of jar libraries of our project .

- activation.jar
- ant.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
- commons-codec-1.3.jar
- commons-collections-3.1.jar
- commons-digester-1.6.jar
- commons-el-1.0.jar
- commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
- commons-io-1.1.jar
- commons-lang-2.1.jar
- commons-net-3.0.1.jar
- commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
- confection-lib-1.0.jar
- edtftpj.jar
- el-api.jar
- el-ri.jar
- groovy-all-1.7.5.jar
- iText-2.1.7.jar
- jasperreports-3.7.6.jar
- javolution-5.5.1.jar
- jsf-facelets.jar
- jstl-1.1.0.jar
- log4j-1.2.15.jar
- myfaces-api-1.1.5.jar
- myfaces-impl-1.1.5.jar
- ojdbc14.jar
- poi-3.8-20120326.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar
- richfaces-api-3.1.6.SR1.jar
- richfaces-impl-3.1.6.SR1.jar
- richfaces-ui-3.1.6.SR1.jar
- standard.jar
- tomahawk-1.1.9.jar

these libraries are placed in a shared lib inside tomcat 5.5.36 : C:\apache-tomcat-5.5.36_\shared\lib

Our web.xml contains this lines :

`

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
        <param-value>classic</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

`

The only thing I change is the 3 jar files for richefaces :

- richfaces-api-3.1.6.SR1.jar
- richfaces-impl-3.1.6.SR1.jar
- richfaces-ui-3.1.6.SR1.jar

and I replace them with these :

- richfaces-api-3.3.3.Final.jar
- richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar
- richfaces-ui-3.3.3.Final.jar

Once I start tomcat i get this stacktrace :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1438)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3743)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4252)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the site findjar.com?  It allows you to search a full class name, and gives you a list of jars that contain that file.  From what I can see there, it looks like you might need to upgrade commons collections to latest version.

Comment: @cobaltduck This didn't work either since com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener is part of mojarra implementation. Not in commons collections as you said.

Comment: Oh, well.  It was worth a shot.  Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: It's ok. Thanks anyway for your time and for being responsive to my problem.

Comment: I think the first step here is to start from the basics.. Have you tried deploying your app in a fresh Tomcat? Looking at your list of libs, there are many there that don't sound like runtime dependencies (obviously this depends on the app's intended functionality), `ant.jar`, `gradle-all-1.7.5.jar`, etc..? For the record: I'm currently experiencing similar issues in a different environment.

Answer (score -1):

this post is old, but you might check the tomahawk and JSF versions.  I think the version of richfaces chosen supports JSF 2.x.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).