# Migrating project from glassfish4 to wildfly 10: Launching error

Tags: java, maven, jsf, jboss, wildfly

I try to migrate my project form glassfish 4 to wildfly 10 but I have this error when trying to launch the application :

```
08:16:19,758 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'app-web.war#jpa'

08:16:19,852 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: jpa
    ...]
08:16:19,950 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-2) Failed to define class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException in Module "javax.faces.api:main" from local module loader @436e852b (finder: local module finder @32d2fa64 (roots: C:\wildfly-10_1\modules,C:\wildfly-10_1\modules\system\layers\base)): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/sun/faces/config/ConfigurationException (Module "javax.faces.api:main" from local module loader @436e852b (finder: local module finder @32d2fa64 (roots: C:\wildfly-10_1\modules,C:\wildfly-10_1\modules\system\layers\base))): javax/faces/FacesException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:606)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

08:16:19,972 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."erp-web.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."erp-web.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "erp-web.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "javax.faces.api:main" from local module loader @436e852b (finder: local module finder @32d2fa64 (roots: C:\wildfly-10_1\modules,C:\wildfly-10_1\modules\system\layers\base))
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/sun/faces/config/ConfigurationException (Module "javax.faces.api:main" from local module loader @436e852b (finder: local module finder @32d2fa64 (roots: C:\wildfly-10_1\modules,C:\wildfly-10_1\modules\system\layers\base))): javax/faces/FacesException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:606)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66)
    ... 10 more
```

Here is my persistence file with the jpa unit :

```
<!-- Génération du schéma de base de données -->
<persistence-unit name="jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <!--  provider -->
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <!-- Classes persistantes -->
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />

        <!--  Logs SQL -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="use_sql_comments" value="false"/>

        <!-- connexion JDBC -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=MY_DB" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="my_user" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="my_psw" />
        <!--  création automatique du schéma -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        <!-- Dialecte -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
        <!--  propriétés DataSource c3p0 -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Could somebody help me to fix the problem ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11778091/5078385) help?

Comment: No, I dont have a listener entry in the web.xml and not .tld files

Comment: I don't think that the problem lies in JPA but rather on JSF implementation on Wildfly; probably you're using Mojjara on Glassfish and MyFaces is running on Wildfly? See [this documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JSF+Configuration) how to configure your favorite JSF-implementation on Wildfly

Comment: WildFly uses Mojara by default. Are you including the jsf-api or jsf-impl libraries in your deployment?

Comment: Yes but now i removed the jsf-api artifactId from my pom.xml and after updating maven project i have many error like : An identification variable must not have the same name as any entity in the same persistence unit. This errors are in my NamedQueries