# Can't inject dependencies to JSF bean with eager=true (Websphere, Myfaces)

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, myfaces

I have a simple eager application scoped JSF bean:

```
@ManagedBean(eager = true, name = "SetupBean")
@ApplicationScoped
public class SetupBean {
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{myBean}")
    private MyBean myBean;
    public void setMyBean(final MyBean myBean) {
        this.myBean = myBean;
    }    
    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        System.err.println("I'm here!");
    }
}
```

While the `@ManagedProperty` line is commented out (no dependecy injection) everything works "OK" (with the exception, I can't do anything useful in that bean).

However, after uncommenting I get the error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This method is not supported during startup

Unfortunatelly, I can't find any useful information WHAT method is not supported during the startup. I know only that there's something wrong with dependency injection. The `MyBean` is nothing special, it's Application Scoped, it has no dependency, it has only some private properties, that need to be configured per application (the bean is in shared library).

Here's the full stack trace:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This method is not supported
>   during startup    at
>   org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.StartupServletExternalContextImpl.getRequestMap(StartupServletExternalContextImpl.java:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.config.ManagedBeanBuilder.getScope(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:540)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.config.ManagedBeanBuilder.getNarrowestScope(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:462)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.config.ManagedBeanBuilder.isInValidScope(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:433)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.config.ManagedBeanBuilder.initializeProperties(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:322)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.config.ManagedBeanBuilder.buildManagedBean(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer._createEagerBeans(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:111)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1678)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:414)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1173)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:772)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1367)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2172)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:663)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5459)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5585)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:677)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:621)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1259)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)     at
>   sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)     at
>   sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)   at
>   javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1148)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:252)
>     at
>   com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
>     at
>   sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
>     at
>   javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1142)
>     at
>   javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:995)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:774)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.startDeployment(StartDeploymentTask.java:247)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.fullAppUpdate(StartDeploymentTask.java:119)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.performTask(StartDeploymentTask.java:107)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor$ExpandApp.expand(AppBinaryProcessor.java:1709)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor.postProcessSynchronousExt(AppBinaryProcessor.java:749)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.postProcess(BLABinaryProcessor.java:590)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.onChangeCompletion(BLABinaryProcessor.java:467)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BinaryProcessorWrapper.onChangeCompletion(BinaryProcessorWrapper.java:109)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.postNotify(FileRepository.java:1924)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.update(FileRepository.java:1433)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.repository.client.LocalConfigRepositoryClient.update(LocalConfigRepositoryClient.java:189)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.update(WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.java:665)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.update(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1998)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.synch(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1946)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceImpl.synch(WorkSpaceImpl.java:549)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.configservice.ConfigServiceImpl.save(ConfigServiceImpl.java:719)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)     at
>   sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)     at
>   sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)   at
>   javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1148)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:252)
>     at
>   com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
>     at
>   sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
>     at
>   javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1142)
>     at
>   javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:995)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:774)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.remote.AdminServiceForwarder.invoke(AdminServiceForwarder.java:346)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1465)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:85)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1306)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1398)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.invoke(_RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.java:751)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnectionImpl_Tie._invoke(_RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.java:158)
>     at
>   com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:669)
>     at
>   com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:523)
>     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:523)   at
>   com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1575)     at
>   com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doRequestWork(Connection.java:3039)   at
>   com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2922)  at
>   com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:64)    at
>   com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1815)

The running configuration: **WebSphere 8.5** with **MyFaces 2.0.2** (IBM custom version).

What does that error mean? What need to be done in order to get the dependency injection work?

Answer (score 1):

Info, http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html

Eager with application. Forces it to load first. Remove eager, seems others have similar bugs [Eager ApplicationScoped managed beans constructed multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007291/eager-applicationscoped-managed-beans-constructed-multiple-times)

There are duplicate packages for the some annotations. Cam u chec. They are right

Comment: Unfortunatelly, eager is exactly what I need, because otherwise I'd have to virtually refer my bean on every site, because there's the logic that must be done once before any other operation is made.