# @ApplicationScoped beans get constructed more than once

Tags: jsf, dependency-injection, managed-bean

I have two managed Java beans:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;

import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/sync")
@ManagedBean(name="syncService", eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class SyncService {
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{ldapDirectoryAccess}")
    private DirectoryAccess directoryAccess;

    public void setDirectoryAccess(DirectoryAccess directoryAccess) {
        System.out.println("SyncService.setDirectoryAccess()");
        this.directoryAccess = directoryAccess;
    }

    public SyncService() {
        System.out.println("SyncService() - constructed: " + this);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("DirectoryAccess injected: " + directoryAccess + " in: " + this);
    }
    ...
}

@ManagedBean(name="ldapDirectoryAccess", eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class LdapDirectoryAccess implements DirectoryAccess {
    public LdapDirectoryAccess() {
        System.out.println("LdapDirectoryAccess constructed: " + this);
    }
    ...
}
```

When I deploy the application in Tomcat, I get the following output in `catalina.out`:

```
SyncService() - constructed: ...SyncService@705ebb4d
...
LdapDirectoryAccess constructed: ...LdapDirectoryAccess@3c1fd5aa
SyncService.setDirectoryAccess()
DirectoryAccess injected: ...LdapDirectoryAccess@3c1fd5aa in:
                          ...SyncService@705ebb4d
LdapDirectoryAccess constructed: ...LdapDirectoryAccess@59d6a4d1
```

So, first an instance of each bean is constructed as expected, and the second bean is injected into the first. But then, another instance of the second bean class is created. How is this possible? In [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_managed_beans) I found the following:

> @ApplicationScoped
>
> Bean lives as long as the web application lives. It gets created upon
>   the first HTTP request involving this bean in the application (or when
>   the web application starts up and the eager=true attribute is set in
>   @ManagedBean) and gets destroyed when the web application shuts down.

So I would expected that one instance of each bean is created when the application is started, and that both instances are destroyed when the application is shut down. But `LdapDirectoryAccess` is constructed twice.

Moreover, when I open the page that is served by `SyncService` I see:

```
SyncService() - constructed: ... SyncService@1cb4a09c
```

so a second instance of `SyncService` is built as well, and I cannot understand why. Also, no `directoryAccess` property is injected this time, and the service throws a null pointer exception.

This means that the first instance of `SyncService` is built correctly, but then

1. A second instance of `SyncService` is created (why?)
2. No `LdapDirectoryAccess` is injected into it (why?)
3. This second instance of `SyncService` is used to serve the call to my REST API. Why this instance and not the first one that was created?

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007291/eager-applicationscoped-managed-beans-constructed-multiple-times) and its answers, however:

- I am using Mojarra 2.2.18
- My application's `web.xml` does not contain any tag mentioning `com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener`

So I after several hours investigation I am completely out of ideas. Do you have any hints?

Answer (score 7):

> A second instance of `SyncService` is created (why?)

Because two different frameworks, completely unaware of each other, are being instructed to manage (instantiate and use) it.

1. JAX-RS, via `@Path`
2. JSF, via `@ManagedBean`

So, in effects, you have one instance of `SyncService` which is managed by JAX-RS, and you have another instance of `SyncService` which is managed by JSF, and only in this instance, the also JSF-specific `@ManagedProperty` is recognized. JAX-RS doesn't understand the `@ManagedProperty` and thus does nothing with it.

Basically, you're here tight-coupling a JAX-RS resource and a JSF managed bean in the very same class. Tight-coupling is a bad programming practice. You need to split out `SyncService` into one independent JAX-RS resource and one independent JSF managed bean. And you'd need to convert the `LdapDirectoryAccess` to use another bean management framework which is recognized by both JAX-RS and JSF, so that a single instance can be injected in both. In modern Java EE 8, that would be a bean managed by CDI's `@javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped`. In legacy Java EE 6/7, you could abuse EJB's `@javax.ejb.Singleton` for that.

Given that you're still using the deprecated `@ManagedBean` instead of its replacement `@Named`, I'll assume that you're still on legacy Java EE, so I'll show only the EJB approach.

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class LdapDirectoryAccessService implements DirectoryAccess {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("LdapDirectoryAccess constructed: " + this);
    }
}
```

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/sync")
public class SyncResource {

    @EJB
    private DirectoryAccess directoryAccess;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("DirectoryAccess injected: " + directoryAccess + " in: " + this);
    }
}
```

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SyncBacking {

    @EJB
    private DirectoryAccess directoryAccess;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("DirectoryAccess injected: " + directoryAccess + " in: " + this);
    }
}
```

Note that being able to inject an EJB in a JAX-RS resource might require additional configuration in Java EE 6/7, for that see the first link of the list below. And, in case you want to `LdapDirectoryAccessService` to eagerly initialize during server's startup, add the `@javax.ejb.Startup` annotation.

#### See also:

- [Inject an EJB into JAX-RS (RESTful service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027834/inject-an-ejb-into-jax-rs-restful-service)
- [JSF Controller, Service and DAO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639785/jsf-controller-service-and-dao)
- [Backing beans (@ManagedBean) or CDI Beans (@Named)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named/)
- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. We are working on a new project and I am learning the technologies along the way. We have been advised to use `JSF` and I did not know that the `@Path` annotation was part of another framework. Also, I did not know that `@ManagedBean` was deprecated since searching for dependency injection in `JSF` I mostly found examples using this annotation. Anyway, thanks for the explanation and all the links: I will try to pick one framework and use it consistently.

Comment: @Giorgio: Google does a very bad job in this regard since if everybody keeps clicking on only articles, they keep getting higher in searchengines. I more and more try to find a common authoritive human maintained site (like e.g. https://jsf.zeef.com) and use that. Yes for that I use google but look for recent (version wise and date wise) links) I do that for other interesting subjects too like solar power etc...

Comment: @BalusC Can i have your email ?