# How to make the web.xml work for Tomcat 7?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>UploadServletApp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>UploadServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.videoreciever.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UploadServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

here is my web.xml. It works well with tomcat 6. But for tomcat 7 it does not work. It do not even deploy. I believe the problem is in the web.xml. The index.jsp includes a form, which includes multiple parameters and also a file.

How to make this work for tomcat7?

Error message on tomcat7, when i try it though Eclipse.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4638)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Why exactly do you think that this problem is related to the `web.xml`? Does the problem disappear if you remove it, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ClassNotFoundException` typically indicates a missing dependency.

You should have a JSF implementation as explained in [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848341/classnotfoundexception-com-sun-faces-config-configurelistener-for-jsf-project-u)