# Cannot deploy Web application to tomcat from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I'm trying deploy a web app to tomcat but getting the next errors

```
    INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\Denis.Belykh\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\IBRSWebTomcatWAR\WEB-INF\lib\javaee-api-6.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
    сен 09, 2014 11:03:42 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
               INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\Denis.Belykh\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\IBRSWebTomcatWAR\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
    сен 09, 2014 11:03:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
    сен 09, 2014 11:03:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
    сен 09, 2014 11:03:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
    сен 09, 2014 11:03:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
    сен 09, 2014 11:03:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
    сен 09, 2014 11:03:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
    сен 09, 2014 11:03:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
    сен 09, 2014 11:03:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
    сен 09, 2014 11:03:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
    сен 09, 2014 11:03:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
    сен 09, 2014 11:03:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
    сен 09, 2014 11:03:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
    сен 09, 2014 11:03:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
    сен 09, 2014 11:03:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
    сен 09, 2014 11:03:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
    сен 09, 2014 11:03:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
    SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:530)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:512)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4907)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'v found the next solution -- to add scope "provided" for dependencies in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But I have no any pom.xml files because I don't use maven in my project!

I'v solved the problem. I was using two libs that contaned jars that were alredy deployed. But the app still doesn't work. Now I have 404 error and this

```
    сен 09, 2014 12:35:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Java/jre7/lib/i386;D:\app\Denis.Belykh\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\eclipse;;.
сен 09, 2014 12:35:14 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:IBRSWebTomcatWAR' did not find a matching property.
сен 09, 2014 12:35:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
сен 09, 2014 12:35:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
сен 09, 2014 12:35:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 632 ms
сен 09, 2014 12:35:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
сен 09, 2014 12:35:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
сен 09, 2014 12:35:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\webapps\docs
сен 09, 2014 12:35:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\webapps\docs has finished in 368 ms
сен 09, 2014 12:35:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\webapps\examples
сен 09, 2014 12:35:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
сен 09, 2014 12:35:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
сен 09, 2014 12:35:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@171ac12')
сен 09, 2014 12:35:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\webapps\examples has finished in 570 ms
сен 09, 2014 12:35:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\webapps\host-manager
сен 09, 2014 12:35:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\webapps\host-manager has finished in 336 ms
сен 09, 2014 12:35:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\webapps\manager
сен 09, 2014 12:35:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\webapps\manager has finished in 310 ms
сен 09, 2014 12:35:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\webapps\ROOT
сен 09, 2014 12:35:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\webapps\ROOT has finished in 285 ms
сен 09, 2014 12:35:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
сен 09, 2014 12:35:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
сен 09, 2014 12:35:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 10016 ms
```

I even can't see the deployment of the project (IBRSWebTomcatWAR) here/

Comment: Are you deploying using WAR?

Comment: No, I'm building project in Eclips

Comment: after you built ,arent you deploying in tomcat?If you are not deploying then why you said this line *m trying deploy a web app to tomcat*

Comment: Ok. Maybe I misunderstand you. I have project and then I run it on server (Tomcat)

Comment: Do you have <listener> <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class> </listener> defined in the web.xml

Comment: No. I'v added this but it doesn't help

Comment: see this  [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848341/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-faces-config-configurelistener

Comment: @Den-Ben Can you show us your project skeleton and your dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was too simple: I used derictory "web" for locating web-content in my project instead of WEB-CONTENT directory. It's pretty obvious, isn't it? :)