# Tomcat 8 throws error : 'A child container failed during start'

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, buildpath

I have been working on a code on my computer and imported that code on other machine. But when I deploy code and run it on the other machine, tomcat doesn't start properly and throws error.

**web.xml file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Try</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
    <display-name>cxf</display-name>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/ *</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <servlet>
    <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jaxrs/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Console Logs:**

> Jan 11, 2017 1:33:12 AM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin WARNING:
>   [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting
>   property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Try' did not find a
>   matching property. Jan 11, 2017 1:33:12 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
>   version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.39
>
> SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Try]]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)Blockquote
>
> Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start
>   component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Try]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to
>   create an instance of type [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.addListener
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)

I have tried other solutions for the same problem on Stack Exchange. But nothing works for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848341/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-faces-config-configurelistener)

Comment: @Berger : I am not using jsf and  'Mojarra' is not in my web.xml.

Comment: `com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener` is a JSF class, something uses it  on your server .

Comment: Same code had been working previously.  Could't find any reference to com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener in source code.

Comment: Still have a look at the above topic, download the jars and put them where the accepted answer says. Maybe one server has this in its libs, and the other one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the causing class `com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener` is present in your computer but not in the target machine. This class usually belongs to `jsf-impl.jar` or `jsf-ri.jar` libraries.

Since you are deploying the same war (I assume) on both machines, that libraries are obivously not into the war, so they are likely to be into your computer's Tomcat runtime: Look for it in directory `<tomcat>/lib` and copy it into the target machine's Tomcat lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem on server.xml file. where we defined `<Context docBase="path" path="/" reloadable="true"/>` on server.xml file so I just removed this while tomcat unpack war.

On **path** your project content will be there like web.xml file, classes, and lib(jars) etc.