# what is the actual reson of using com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener in web.xml of a JSF Project

Tags: jsf, configuration, web.xml

I'm a beginner to JSF Framework. When I enable the jsf capabilities in my maven project. It's automatically generating some XML codes inside the web.xml. But I don't know what they actually do?. can anyone explain me about last three tags.
[image]

[image]

explain the last picture I have attached

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, post the code itself using the right formatting!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848341/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-faces-config-configurelistener