# ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, primefaces

I have an error when run my spring mvc web application.

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
>
> at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:544)

...

My jdk version is : `jdk1.8.0_151`

Application Server : `Apache Tomcat 8.5.24`

IDE : `IntelliJ IDEA`

I dont know this error come from where.

web.xml? faces-config.xml? spring framework version? Tomcat version? jdk version?

Comment: If you don't bundle JSF you need to use a Java EE web server (web profile will do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you need to add JSF libraries to your classpath, as bare-bone tomcat don't provide it like other application servers.

Similar question is also posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848341/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-faces-config-configurelistener)